# Use Ajax in pager in custom module

Tags: views

how can i use ajax in pager

```
$pager = [
  '#type' => 'pager',
];

return [
  '#theme'      => 'news_filter',
  '#articles'   => $articles,
  '#categories' => $categories,
  '#count_res'  => count($nids),
  '#pager'      => $pager,
  '#attached'   => [
    'library' => [
      'news_filter/news_filter.assets',
    ],
  ],
];
```

it's very urgent thank you for answering me

Comment: I don't know your code, so I can't say what will work, but from knowing Drupal's render array API, I can see that this `'#pager'  => $pager,` should be `'pager' => $pager,`

Comment: Check this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/8.2.x  look at exemples

Comment: the pagination function problem how do i add an ajax to a pagination